# Concatenate Number and Text based on condition in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I would like to concatenate a `number` and `text` based on a condition. For example:

`CASE WHEN quantity = 1 THEN CONCAT(quantity, 'Item')  ELSE CONCAT(quantity, 'Items') END`

Result:

```
1 Item
2 Items
3 Items
...
20 Items
```

Presently, THEN/ELSE statements do not accept functions. Is there an alternative method to achieve the above result in data studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way it can be achieved is by creating the below [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) which uses the [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443) function to join the `Quantity` field with the text  `Items` (note that the single space   before `Items` is intentional) and then the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) function to ensure that `1 Items` is replaced by `1 Item`:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(quantity, " Items"), "^(1 Items)$", "1 Item")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/77949df6-8857-47fc-8ee7-38cc17ef33c5) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]